# What is the difference between vector-valued functions and parametric equations?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

So as it is, I'm now starting to cover **vector-valued functions** in my Calculus III class. While studying the topic, I noticed that it *seemed* to be the exact same thing as **parametric equations.** I know that I am probably missing an important difference between the two topics, but I can't seem to figure it out.

So the question is:

> What is the difference between a set of parametric equations and a vector-valued function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that a parametrization has some extra properties. A vector valued function is a map $$f:U\subset\mathbb R^m\to V\subset\mathbb R^n$$

And parametric equations for a [portion of a] submanifold $M$ in Euclidean space (it's rare to parametrize things other than manifolds) is a map $$\varphi:U\subset\mathbb R^m\to M\subset\mathbb R^n$$
Where:

- $U$ is open
- $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image
- $\operatorname{rank}D\varphi = m$ everywhere

What we could say then, is that a parametrization is always in the form of a vector valued function, but conversely, we use vector valued functions with nice properties to parametrize varieties.

Comment: Downvote? What did I say wrong?

Comment: Why is a parametric derivative different than the derivative of a vector-valued function?  There doesn't seem to be anything in your definition of parametric that breaks the symmetry between the components of the vector-valued output,  yet they are treated differently in the parametric derivative.  For example, y is treated as a function of t and x, while x is treated as a function of t.

Comment: @user10478 I have never heard of the term "parametric derivative" and to be honest I can't make sense of the rest of your comment either, sorry.

Comment: What did you say wrong? Someone learning calculus doesn't know about what is an homepomorphism or an algebraic structure. This is what is wrong.

Comment: True, but answers don’t always have to be aimed at the OP. Answers are written for everyone who might see this thread in the future. If someone has an insightful way of looking at something, it can be helpful to share. I got something out of this answer.

Comment: @İbrahimİpek As it turns out I was a calculus student myself at the time of writing it. That was what I was taught so it seemed appropriate. Later did I understand that calculus meant something much different at US schools, but it would simply have been impossible to appreciate that at the time.

Comment: @GPerez As is it formulated I don't understand how the answer highlights the differences. Is it that saying "vector valued function" means the input and output domains are very general, but saying "parametric function" implies the output is some points in the euclidean space that belongs to a sub-manifold (so a shape like curves or surfaces). Speaking to the broader audience is good, if it is to include more people. All due respect, I feel like it presently excludes from the conversation most people and could be improved. We could use concrete examples and simpler explanation on the side.

Answer (score 3):

They are basically the same (different ways of expressing the same idea).

In the equation below, the LHS is a vector-valued function, and the RHS is a parametric form of the same function.

$$\vec{v} = \pmatrix{\sin{(t)} \\ \cos{(t)} \\ t} 
\equiv \matrix{x(t) = \sin{(t)} \\ y(t) = \cos{(t)} \\ z(t) = t}$$